# Amazon RDS: Launching "db.t1.micro" instances using the JAVA SDK

Tags: java, amazon-rds

I'm trying to start a new MySql Instance on Amazon RDS using the Java API and the following code:

```
CreateDBInstanceRequest createDBInstanceRequest = new CreateDBInstanceRequest();
createDBInstanceRequest.setEngine("MySQL");     
createDBInstanceRequest.setLicenseModel("general-public-license");
createDBInstanceRequest.setEngineVersion("5.5.25a");
createDBInstanceRequest.setDBInstanceClass("db.t1.micro");  
createDBInstanceRequest.setMultiAZ(false);
createDBInstanceRequest.setAutoMinorVersionUpgrade(true);
createDBInstanceRequest.setAllocatedStorage(5);  
createDBInstanceRequest.setDBInstanceIdentifier("mydbinstance");
createDBInstanceRequest.setMasterUsername("master");
createDBInstanceRequest.setMasterUserPassword("password");
createDBInstanceRequest.setDBName("dbname");
createDBInstanceRequest.setPort(3306);
createDBInstanceRequest.setDBParameterGroupName("default.mysql5.5");
createDBInstanceRequest.setDBSubnetGroupName("dev");
createDBInstanceRequest.setBackupRetentionPeriod(1);
DBInstance dbInstance = RDS.createDBInstance(createDBInstanceRequest);
```

The problem is that this always results in the following error:

> AWS Error Code: InsufficientDBInstanceCapacity, AWS Error Message:
>   Cannot create a database instance because there is no availability
>   zone with sufficient capacity. Please try your request again at a
>   later time.

As suggested, I tried at a later time but have never been able to launch a new instance programatically but when I try to launch an instance using the Amazon Mgmt Console, using exactly the same parameters, it launches instantly.

I have also noticed that this problem only occurs with DB Instance Class "db.t1.micro".
Is this instance class not available through the API?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain this exact version of MySQL is available in any of the availability zones in your region?

I would suggest to execute [DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeOrderableDBInstanceOptions.html) for your engine of choice first, filter using your own criteria (e.g. DBInstanceClass="db.t1.micro") and then select the version from that.